# My .html() rewrite my form when i use a ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using a `ajax` call which is making a form in a `php` function and gives that form back. The form is in a `foreach` so u got some forms in one page, but not form in form.

But, when I send the `html` to `jquery` and do `.html(data)` (after succes of the `ajax` call), the form is placed close tag above the inputs and so the form doesn't work. Does `.html` `jquery` tag support `<form>` tags?

Im using this code in the function:

```
<?= form_open(route_to('addLink')) ?>
    <input type="input" class="form-control mb-2" name="url" placeholder="Volledige url" />
<?= form_close() ?>
```

But when I use `jquery` like this:

```
success: function (data)
{
    $('.bodyContent').html(data);
}
```

... it generates this instead of the form I send:

```
<form action="https://linkform.nl/addLink" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"></form>
<input type="input" class="form-control mb-2" name="url" placeholder="Volledige url">
```

When I do `console.log()` BEFORE the `html()` it is correctly..

Comment: What is `.bodyContent`, and what does it currently contain at this point, before you add the form? Questions like this should always come with a proper [mre].

Comment: And what is the exact data returned from the route?

Comment: Before i add the form `.bodyContent` has just text in it. But when they use the search form, the ajax call will used. And, the exactly data returned from the route is the first code i add in my post.